# WAN connectivity drops out

Tags: networking

I am using openwrt on a router that connects to a dedicated modem. At random times, I find my internet drop out, whilst the LAN is still connectable. This happens with 2 different types of modems and I am unable to see much out of the ordinary from the openwrt interface. Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips for me to pursue? I know it is a problem with the router, as an alternate device works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check syslog in router?

Set DNS to:

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

Turn off any 'ethernet energy save mode' via system (or device) settings.

Anyway it is hard to say where lies the problem. Dropouts may be even caused by wrong MTU size. Check here for "Troubleshooting WAN" topic: [LINK](http://www.networktutorials.info/data/wan-troubleshooting.html) There are few tips and diagnostic tools that can help you specify your problem. This isn't much but this is a good start.